# Passing udp unix socket as input to ffmpeg

Tags: unix, ffmpeg, udp

I already know that ffmpeg is able to receive input from a unix socket:

```
ffmpeg -i unix://path-to-socket ...
```

Problem is that once changing the socket type to `SOCK_DGRAM` instead of `SOCK_STREAM` in my server code, ffmpeg is not able to receive the data and an error is printed:

```
unix://path-to-socket: Protocol wrong type for socket
```

looking at the [socket documentation on ffmpeg's site](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#unix) the following options can be applied:

- **timeout**: Timeout in ms.
- **listen**: Create the Unix socket in listening mode.

which are not relevant for the declaring the socket type.

ls configuring the unix socket to `SOCK_DGRAM` even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is incomplete. In `ffmpeg/libavformat/unix.c`,

```
static const AVOption unix_options[] = {
    { "listen",    "Open socket for listening",             OFFSET(listen),  AV_OPT_TYPE_BOOL,  { .i64 = 0 },                    0,       1, ED },
    { "timeout",   "Timeout in ms",                         OFFSET(timeout), AV_OPT_TYPE_INT,   { .i64 = -1 },                  -1, INT_MAX, ED },
    { "type",      "Socket type",                           OFFSET(type),    AV_OPT_TYPE_INT,   { .i64 = SOCK_STREAM },    INT_MIN, INT_MAX, ED, "type" },
    { "stream",    "Stream (reliable stream-oriented)",     0,               AV_OPT_TYPE_CONST, { .i64 = SOCK_STREAM },    INT_MIN, INT_MAX, ED, "type" },
    { "datagram",  "Datagram (unreliable packet-oriented)", 0,               AV_OPT_TYPE_CONST, { .i64 = SOCK_DGRAM },     INT_MIN, INT_MAX, ED, "type" },
    { "seqpacket", "Seqpacket (reliable packet-oriented",   0,               AV_OPT_TYPE_CONST, { .i64 = SOCK_SEQPACKET }, INT_MIN, INT_MAX, ED, "type" },
    { NULL }
};
```

it handles `stream=1`, `datagram=1`, `seqpacket=1`, or `type=#`, where `#` is the integer value of the desired socket type (`SOCK_STREAM=1`, `SOCK_DGRAM=2`, `SOCK_SEQPACKET=5`).

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Could you expand on how to use these options on the command line?